# ansible AWX is connecting through ssh as root instead of user defined in credential

Tags: ansible, awx

I'm running ansible 2.6.2 and awx 1.0.7.2 on rhel 7.5. AWX is connecting to my ssh proxy as root instead of the defined Credential user.

My playbook contains the following

```
become: yes
become_method: sudo
remote_user: remoteuser
ansible_user: remoteuser
```

ssh.config in my playbook contain the following

```
match host !proxyA,!proxyB,* exec "ssh proxyA nc -w1 %h %p &>/dev/null
  ProxyJump proxyA
match host !proxyA,!proxyB,* exec "ssh proxyB nc -w1 %h %p &>/dev/null
  ProxyJump proxyB
```

My AWX credential user which uses an ssh key and associated with the AWX JOB Template is this (which should be used for ssh connections):  remoteuser

I have no defined entries in /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg or any ansible.cfg defined in the current working directory (of the playbook) or in $HOME.

Here is the proxyA/B syslog entries showing the user that AWX is connecting as:

sshd: Failed publickey fro root from 1.2.3.4

And here is the AWX ansible output showing the connection as 'root' instead of the 'remoteuser'

root@proxyA's password: root@proxyA's password:  root@proxyA's password:

I can run the playbook through ansible (outside of AWX) without errors.

How do I tell AWX to use the right user name?

Comment: You are specifying (or rather not) the user for the proxy in the proxy command. 'ssh user@proxyA -W %h:%p'  ansible specifies the remote user in the connection to the host it jumps to through this proxy. You could try %r as user.

Comment: tried that and still connected as root.  Not sure why, I'll keep looking.  Thanks.

Comment: Could you indicate whether you solved the issue?

Comment: Is [this](https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/9017/210) related?

Answer (score 1):

According to https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_intro.html

it should be `remote_user:` if it still does not work, run the playbook with `-vvvv` and add the log to the Q&A.